# Using PostgreSQL Logical Replication in Go

Tags: postgresql, go, wal

I'm working on using Postgres logical replication in Go using the [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) library to get database changes via a logical replication slot using wal2json as the output plugin. The Postgres version being used is `v10.1`.

When in the `WaitForReplicationMessage` loop, I receive a message, and if that message is a [`ServerHeartbeat`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#ServerHeartbeat), I [send a standby status](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#ReplicationConn.SendStandbyStatus) message to update the server of my consumed position in  the WAL.  This [`StandbyStatus`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#StandbyStatus) message has a field called `ReplyRequested` which, if equals `1` tells the server to send a `ServerHeartbeat`; and if the value is `0` it's not supposed to do anything.

Now I'm sending a `StandbyStatus` message with the `ReplyRequested` value to `0` (which is the default value when the object is created). On sending this, the server sends a heartbeat message despite me telling it not to. I'm unable to see the cause of this issue.

Here's my code:

```
    for {
    log.Info("Waiting for message")

    message, err := session.ReplConn.WaitForReplicationMessage(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Errorf("%s", reflect.TypeOf(err))
        continue
    }

    if message.WalMessage != nil {
        log.Info(string(message.WalMessage.WalData))
    } else if message.ServerHeartbeat != nil {
        log.Info("Heartbeat requested")
        // set the flushed LSN (and other LSN values) in the standby status and send to PG
        log.Info(message.ServerHeartbeat)

        // send Standby Status with the LSN position            
        err = session.sendStandbyStatus()
        if err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Error("Unable to send standby status")
        }

    }
}
```

The `sendStandbyStatus` function above is:

```
func (session *Session) sendStandbyStatus() error {
  standbyStatus, err := pgx.NewStandbyStatus(session.RestartLSN)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  log.Info(standbyStatus) // the output of this confirms ReplyRequested is indeed 0
  standbyStatus.ReplyRequested = 0 // still set it
  err = session.ReplConn.SendStandbyStatus(standbyStatus)
  if err != nil {
      return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for this but just wanted to know where you receiving Heartbeat message. I'm ain't getting any?

Comment: @Noobie: Here https://github.com/sidmutha/pgdeltastream/blob/master/db/lr.go#L61 

you'll have to explore the code a bit to understand but this is how I was doing it